# IP addresses from around the globe show up in my Router logs

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, logging

I was checking my Wifi Router logs, and i spotted a lot of the following -

```
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 198.204.230.34:5109 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UDP:5060
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 107.181.174.205:55372 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TCP:23
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 207.244.71.161:5084 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UDP:5060
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 198.143.173.187:60348 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UDP:623
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 91.121.236.231:80 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TCP:37990
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 198.204.245.26:5084 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx UDP:5060
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 110.45.244.147:32152 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TCP:22
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 93.174.93.51:50530 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TCP:3128
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 117.27.254.25:57594 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TCP:9300
Unrecognized attempt blocked from 218.77.79.43:34012 to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TCP:23
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx being the DHCP address allocated to my machine by my ISP. The sheer volume of these is staggering. Looking up the physical location of these IPs, they are coming in from China, Netherlands, Atlanta, etc. And they are trying to hit all kinds of ports.

Some Internet forums/discussion boards say this is a very common occurrence. Is it? Have any of your experienced this? Any other measures that I can/should take other than just letting the router do its job?

Comment: You don't show any timestamps on the log entries so I can't tell how often these occur. Anyway, this is quite normal as long you're not getting these every second or more. 3128 is squid proxy so someone's looking for an open proxy; 5060 is SIP so someone's looking to make cheap phone calls; 23 is telnet, 22 is ssh, etc. Get used to the fact there are a lot of people out there that are criminals.

Comment: Make sure you don't still have the default password for admin access - that's one of the easiest ways in for these people.

Comment: Yea, I remember installing bitvise ssh server on my computer and forwarding 22 to my pc.. I frequently got auth attempts with root/root, root/toor and other default combos.  The internet is full of bots looking for easy prey.

Comment: 1. Those log events are spaced 2 seconds apart. For a few minutes there is a flurry of activity, then quite for a few more minutes. Cycle repeats multiple times every hour.
2. No default credentials or ports are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users have suggested above, this seems to be a very common problem, and a very good reason to maintain/update your router firmware and check your router settings frequently.